# VueJS how to rerender a component

Tags: vue.js, state, updates

I have a VueJS component which populates a table via ajax, than I have a modal form inside component which creates new entries in table.

On modal hide I want to update the table to show new entries.

```
export default {
        created() {
            axios.get('/api/v1/customers')
                .then(response => {
                    this.customers = response.data;
                });
        },

        methods: {

            store() {
                this.form.errors = [];

                axios.post('/api/v1/customers', this.form)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.form.name = '';
                        this.form.scopes = [];
                        this.form.errors = [];

                        $('#modal-edit-client').modal('hide');
                        this.$forceUpdate();
                    })
                    .catch(error => {

                        console.log(error)
                        /*if (typeof error.response.data === 'object') {
                            this.form.errors = _.flatten(_.toArray(error.response.data));
                        } else {
                            this.form.errors = ['Something went wrong. Please try again.'];
                        }*/
                    });
            },

            newUser: function () {
                $('#modal-edit-client').modal('show');
            },

            edit: function () {
                alert('edit modal')
            }
        },

        data() {
            return {
                customers: {},
                alert: {
                    show: false,
                    type: null,
                    title: null,
                    message: null,
                },
                form: {
                    scopes: [],
                    errors: []
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

I tried to use `$forceUpdate()` but does not seems to work

output template

```
<template>
    <div class="row" v-cloak>
        <div class="col-md-12 ">
            <div class="panel panel-default custom-panel">

                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <strong>Customers</strong>
                    <div id="custom-search-input">
                        <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                            <input v-on:keyup.enter="filter" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search Customer" />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <a class="btn icon-btn btn-success" id="new__item" href="#" @click="newUser">
                        <span class="glyphicon btn-glyphicon glyphicon-plus img-circle text-success"></span> Add Customer
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
                            <th>Firma</th>
                            <th>Strasse</th>
                            <th>PLZ</th>
                            <th>Ort</th>
                            <th>Tel</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr v-for="customer in customers">
                            <td>{{ customer.id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ customer.customer_name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ customer.customer_street }}</td>
                            <td>{{ customer.customer_plz }}</td>
                            <td>{{ customer.customer_city }}</td>
                            <td>{{ customer.customer_telephone }}</td>
                            <td><span class="badge bg-green"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span></td>
                            <td class="actions">
                                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Edit Client Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="modal-edit-client" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="spinner"></div>
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button " class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

                        <h4 class="modal-title">
                            Add Customer
                        </h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <!-- Form Errors -->
                        <!--<div class="alert alert-danger" v-if="alert" >
                            <p><strong>Whoops!</strong> Something went wrong!</p>
                            <br>
                        </div>-->

                        <!-- Edit Client Form -->

                        <form class="form-horizontal" id="modal-create-customer"  role="form" method="POST" action="">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <label for="customer_name" class="control-label">Firmenbezeichnung</label>
                                    <input id="customer_name" type="text" class="form-control" v-model="form.customer_name" name="customer_name" value="" required autofocus>

                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong></strong>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <label for="sex" class="control-label">Anrede</label>
                                    <select v-model="form.customer_contact_sex" name="title" id="sex" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="Herr">Herr</option>
                                        <option value="Frau">Frau</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong></strong>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <label for="title" class="control-label">Title</label>
                                    <select v-model="form.customer_contact_title" name="title" id="title" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="">No title</option>
                                        <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
                                        <option value="Prof.">Prof.</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong></strong>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <label for="name" class="control-label">First Name</label>

                                    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" v-model="form.customer_first_name" name="customer_name" value="" required autofocus>


                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong></strong>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <label for="email" class="control-label">Last Name</label>

                                    <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" v-model="form.customer_last_name" name="customer_last_name" value="" required>

                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong></strong>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <label for="street" class="control-label">Street</label>

                                    <input id="street" type="text" class="form-control" v-model="form.customer_street" name="customer_street" value="" required>

                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong></strong>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-2">
                                    <label for="plz" class="control-label">PLZ</label>

                                    <input id="plz" type="text" class="form-control" v-model="form.customer_plz" name="customer_plz" value="" required>

                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong></strong>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-4">
                                    <label for="city" class="control-label">City</label>

                                    <input id="city" type="text" class="form-control" v-model="form.customer_city" name="customer_city" value="" required>

                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong></strong>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <label for="customer_telephone" class="control-label">Tel.</label>

                                    <input id="customer_telephone" type="text" class="form-control" v-model="form.customer_telephone" name="customer_telephone" value="" required>

                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong></strong>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <label for="customer_fax" class="control-label">Fax.</label>

                                    <input id="customer_fax" type="text" class="form-control" name="customer_fax" value="" required>

                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong></strong>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <label for="customer_mobile" class="control-label">Mobil</label>

                                    <input id="customer_mobile" type="text" class="form-control" name="customer_mobile" value="" required>

                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong></strong>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <label for="customer_email" class="control-label">E-Mail.</label>

                                    <input id="customer_email" type="text" class="form-control" name="customer_email" value="" required>

                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong></strong>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <label for="customer_note" class="control-label">Notiz</label>

                                    <textarea name="csutomer_note" id="customer_note" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong></strong>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal Actions -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="store">
                            Register
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: It looks like you're resetting the form when you get a response from the server but you're not getting any data from it. Wouldn't you need to get the customers from the response and put it the component's property?

Comment: Show the table output code

Comment: The idea is that the table should have a link to the table. When you get the status that the new field is added - add this data to the array and vue reactively displays a new field

Comment: I added the output, I'm quite new to vuejs

Comment: In your `store()` post request what response do you get back in the promise?

Comment: 2 cases: 1. error message as json if data could not be saved or if everything went alright than a 2. success message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comments, your code looks fine except that you're not actually updating the `customers` property with anything.
When you're performing the XHR request with Axios, you need to use the response to populate the component, which will automatically update the relevant DOM.
Here is the relevant part of your code that you should modify:

```
axios.post('/api/v1/customers', this.form)
.then(response => {
  this.form.name = '';
  this.form.scopes = [];
  this.form.errors = [];

  // Set the component's customers property to what you get 
  // in the response
  this.customers = response.data.customers;

  $('#modal-edit-client').modal('hide');

  // You don't need to forceUpdate as Vue will take care of 
  // rerendering the relevant parts of the DOM
  // this.$forceUpdate();
})
```

Also, considering you're expecting an array of customers to render the table, you should set the `customers` default value accordingly:

```
data() {
  return {
    customers: []
    // ...
  };
}
```

Comment: thanks for feedback, I jut tried the code but in this case customers on store will be empty

Comment: Well you need to adapt the code to match what's returned by your API, using `console.log()` might help you debugging this part.

Comment: reference from official documentation: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Controlling-Reusable-Elements-with-key